# How do I load a kernel module without root?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, v4l2loopback

I'm making a program which requires a kernel module. I load this module with the
following code:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "-S", "modprobe", "v4l2loopback")
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error starting v4l2loopback: ", err.Error())
}
```

This works, but it requires the user to enter their password, meaning that the program has to be started in a terminal. I think there is a way to load this module, `v4l2loopback`, without the root password, because [this program](https://github.com/aramg/droidcam/) does it, but it ships with its own version of `v4l2loopback` and is written in C. Is there a way to do this conveniently without requiring the root password?

Comment: You can add commands to the /etc/sudoers file that can be run without a password, but beware that this opens a security hole.

Comment: thank you! I'm looking for something a little bit more portable, though

Comment: The program you refer to uses `sudo` to load the module -- at least, that's what I see in the `Makefile`. You need elevated privileges to load kernel modules, even if you've written them yourself.

Comment: You could configure the system to load the module automatically on system boot using the systemd-modules-load.service or something equivalent if not using SystemD (such as the /etc/modules file).

Comment: thank you! I hadn't noticed that. After installing the program, it uses insmod, and then I notice that the module gets loaded automatically at startup. Does insmod do this automatically, or is there some option I have to give it to emulate this behaviour, or what?